The Get Token Holder List by Contract Address API is not working Etherscan Pro API
The Get Token Holder List by Contract Address API is not working Etherscan Pro API.
I enter my correct contract address, as you can see here:
https://etherscan.io/token/0x8881c19665bbf8fa0677900d0e6c689e71bd8db7
And the Pro API, but I can't access it.
What's going wrong?
The error I get is:
{
  "status": "0",
  "message": "No token holder found",
  "result": []
}

I need to get the total holders.
